# raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, urllib

Manga (Japanese comics) aren't available in pdf but in raw images, so I created a tool that would automatically download the photos.

Here's my code

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

responsePage = input("Enter URL: ")
response = requests.get(responsePage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.findAll('img')

image_name = 0

for img in images[1:-1]:
    image_name += 1
    url = img['src']
    full_name = str(image_name) + '.jpg'
    print(response.headers)
    resource_image = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
    print(full_name + " Saved!")
```

The error I receive is:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's forbidden error, means the URL you entered require authentication and you are not allowed to access it until you authorize yourself

Comment: so, anyway i can solve this?

Comment: you need to write code to authorize yourself using any method supported by url, you didn't mentioned any url so all I can suggest is to check yourself how you can authorize with token/session or credentials

Comment: well, the url is

Comment: https://manganelo.com/chapter/read_detective_conan_manga_online_free/chapter_10

Comment: just an example

Comment: also, the website doesn't require any username' password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def download_image(url, path):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)

URL = "https://manganelo.com/chapter/read_detective_conan_manga_online_free/chapter_10"
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.findAll('img')
for i in images:
    url = i.attrs["src"]
    os.makedirs(url.split('/')[-2], exist_ok=True)
    download_image(url, os.path.join(url.split('/')[-2], url.split('/')[-1]))
```